# material ui warning in using `textField` component with `select`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using TextField as the input param of Select gives the following warning:

> Material-UI: `children` must be passed when using the `TextField` component with `select`.

```
<Select
    multiple        
    value="value"
    fullWidth
    input={
        <TextField name="name" id="id" variant="outlined" label="test"/>
    }
>
 <MenuItem>1</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem>2</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

What is the proper implementation of the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way is to render a `TextField` as parent component, and providing it `select` prop

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100px'
  },
}));

export default function SelectTextField() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (   
    <TextField 
    classes={{root:classes.root}}
    select
    name="name" 
    id="id" 
    variant="outlined" 
    label="test"
    SelectProps={{
      multiple: true,
      value: []
    }}
    >
      <MenuItem>1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>2</MenuItem>
    </TextField>
    );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-orzo8)

Comment: SelectProps worked for me. Didn't need to do `value: []` though. Instead I destructured `SelectProps` and did `SelectProps={{ ...SelectProps, multiple: true }}`

Comment: Weird, but does nothing when using this code in Solid and SUID. I just get a plain old TextField without the Select functionality.